# Circle Tangent question

Tags: analytic-geometry

I would like to ask for assiatance on the following:

Find the eqation of a circle, with a radius of$\sqrt 2$ , which also has as tangetns the lines: $  y=x+2 $ ,  $ y=-7x $. It is known that the circle is in the first quadrant.

A possible solution would be to construct the tangent equations to the circle but this turns out to be quite complex.. What are possible ways of solution here?

Comment: The center of the circle must lie at their bisector, then, having the radius you can determine what you want.

Comment: Is there such a thing as bisector eqation of the circle, which goes to the starting point of the two tagnents?

Comment: Sorry, I meant angle bisector. [There is](http://www.ditutor.com/line/equation_bisector.html), in fact, and you can see that there would be $4$ such circles if we didn't consider that it is in the first quadrant. I think a geometric approach would be better, though.

Comment: I did write a huge hint to this question...but then you deleted your question (**exactly** this same one!) and all my effort was in vane. I hate that and I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: I appreciate that, but you must understand that I do not have the ability to monitor when someone is on the process of writing an answer to a certain question, and when I see that a question has relatively little to no appropriate responses, I have to reask again. If it will be deleted I will post again, and if that will be deleted I will post again and again, until I receive an appropriate answer or get deleted from this site.